# How can I optimize when I update UI by async data in Compose of Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to get data asynchronously from the remote server when I use OpenAI API.

The UI will be updated  when Action 1, Action 2 or Action 3 return new data.

The Code A can work , but the  structure of Code A is too ugly, how can I optimize Code A?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    var userData: String by remember { mutableStateOf("OK") }
    var imageURL1: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var imageURL2: String by remember { mutableStateOf("") }   
    var k: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {       
        val openAI = OpenAI("sk-...")

        val ada = openAI.model(modelId = ModelId("text-ada-001"))

        val completionRequest = CompletionRequest(
            model = ada.id,
            prompt = "Somebody once told me the world is gonna roll me"
        )
      
       // Action 1
        userData = userData + "\n\n" + "Completetion:"
        openAI.completion(completionRequest).choices.forEach {
            k = k + 1
            userData = userData + "\n" + "RowA $k: " + it.text
        }

       // Action 2
        userData = userData + "\n\n" + "Stream:"
        k = 0
        openAI.completions(completionRequest)
            .onEach {
                k = k + 1
                userData = userData + "\n" + "RowB $k: " + it.choices[0].text + "       AI"
            }
            .onCompletion { println() }
            .launchIn(this)
            .join()
      
       // Action 3
        val images = openAI.imageURL(
            creation = ImageCreation(
                prompt = "A asian pretty girl",
                n = 2,
                size = ImageSize.is256x256
            )
        )
        imageURL1 = images[0].url
        imageURL2 = images[1].url    
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        if (userData == "OK") {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
            Text(text = "Wait...")
        } else {          
            NetworkImage(imageURL1)
            NetworkImage(imageURL2)         
            Text("Information: $userData")
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun NetworkImage(url: String) {
    val painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = url
    )
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = "Network Image",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .height(256.dp)
    )
}
```